# R - How to download a .pdf that is locked?

Tags: r, pdf, download, passwords

I can download perfectly a PDF from a website that is not locked with the next commands:

```
 require(XML)
url <- ('http://www.eluniversal.com.mx/impreso/wportada_20121202.pdf')
download.file(url, 'universal.pdf')
```

But for a website that needs a Password I can't. After I download it and I'm trying to open it, is says that the file may be corrupted. Here is the link example:

```
require(XML)
url <- ('http://www.reforma.com/edicionimpresa/paginas/20121201/pdfs/rPRI20121201-001.pdf')
download.file(url, 'reforma.pdf')
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the pdf file and everything to do with your lack of security credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do have a password to enter the site, you can try logging into it using internet explorer before starting R; R needs a cookie to access secure websites.

Comment: Do you know how to activate the cookies in R?

Comment: They should be activated automatically. One thing to try would be toggling the `mode` switch in `download.file`. Try `download.file(url, destfile, mode = 'wb')`.  This has worked for me in the past when a file has appeared to be "corrupted".